# Loop a CSS Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

So I've got this nice CSS animation here and I would like it to loop.

I have almost no experience with CSS animations yet sadly and no Idea how to do this.
I'd really appreciate if somebody here could help me out a bit.
Thank you!

HTML

```
<div id="msg">Weeeeeee</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#msg").click(function() {
    var duration = 1400;
    $msg = $(this);
    $msg.css("-webkit-transform", "scale(2)")
        .css("-webkit-transition-timing-function", "ease-out")
        .css("-webkit-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $msg.css("-webkit-transform", "scale(1)")
            .css("-webkit-transition-timing-function", "ease-in")
            .css("-webkit-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
    }, duration);
});
```

CSS

```css
#msg { font-size: 40pt; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; line-height: 120pt; }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Praveen's solution should be closer to what you asked for, but I'll provide a solution [using CSS3 animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations) instead of using jQuery to animate transitions. IMO it is easier to maintain and understand:

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes foo {
  from {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform:scale(2);
  }
}
```

Then JS:

```
$("#msg").click(function() {
    var duration = 1400;
    $msg = $(this);
    //syntax is: animation-name animation-duration[ animation-timing-function][ animation-delay][ animation-iteration-count][ animation-direction]
    $msg.css("animation", "foo " + duration + "ms ease infinite alternate");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sFxPk/1/)

I didn't use the optional `animation-delay` parameter in the above, the rest should be pretty straightforward. `infinite` iteration count with `alternate` direction will execute the animation indefinitely alternating the animation direction from (`from` to `to` ) to (`to` to `from`) until you call `$msg.css("animation", "")` to remove the animation.

ps. jQuery 1.8+ will do the prefixing in the JS automatically for you.
Of course, you still have to prefix the CSS to work in non-webkit browsers though. [Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/) should do it.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sFxPk/2/) with prefixed CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please also tell me how to start the animation onload? I've tried to replace the `$("#msg").click(function() {` with `$(document).ready(function () {` but it didn't work...

Comment: @Matt You'll probably have to change `$msg = $(this);` to `$msg = $('#msg');` inside the document ready function. `=]` Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFxPk/3/)

Comment: @Matt No problem. `=]` Also, if you want to start the animation on page load, you could put the `animation` in the `#msg` css too. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFxPk/4/) - of course it is a little more code in the CSS, but then it'd run even with JS disabled. Not that it matters for most nowadays' sites which are greatly based on JS frameworks, but still can be considered if you ever plan on making a huge site with progressive enhancement/graceful degradation that takes into consideration JS-disabled browsers. `:P`

Comment: I'm ashamed to say that there's still one very last thing I need help with. The div I've used yet has always been rotated ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9c98F/)). Is there any way to also add that feature? I tried my best and even with jQuery I couldn't make it. :(

Comment: @Matt don't worry, this one is a little more tricky. Both `rotate` and `scale` are part of the `transform` CSS property, and you can't define 2 properties with the same name (in either CSS rule, element style or animation) otherwise one will overwrite the other. You have to concatenate both transforms into a single one by separating both transform property values with spaces inside of one `transform` property declaration. As you have one transform in the animation and that one must take effect, you will have to add the `rotate` inside of the animation's transform.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's really nice that you just go around and help people like that. Have a good day! :)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Thanks buddy... Kinda not feeling good to undelete my answer as it has two downvotes! `:(`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I see that you've posted 2 answers, one of them isn't deleted. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I think it would be better to consolidate the animation into a class and simply use jquery to add/remove the class. That way you have separation of concerns.

Comment: @hitautodestruct right, that's the approach I usually take nowadays. I just kept the animation property in JS as OP was using a JS var to determine the animation's duration, but you can refactor the CSS property(ies) into a CSS class and use `addClass`/`removeClass` as long as there are no dynamic values involved in your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

#### Encapsulate everything inside `setInterval()`

```
var duration = 1400;
$msg = $(this);
setInterval(function(){
    $msg.css("-webkit-transform", "scale(2)")
        .css("-webkit-transition-timing-function", "ease-out")
        .css("-webkit-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $msg.css("-webkit-transform", "scale(1)")
            .css("-webkit-transition-timing-function", "ease-in")
            .css("-webkit-transition-duration", duration + "ms");
    }, duration);
}, duration);
```

Does this help? And yeah, please correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: I guess the outer `setInterval` should be `duration * 2`, but using callbacks inside a self-executing function would be cleaner IMHO as it wouldn't depend on timeout/intervals oh wait, you can't use callbacks as the effect comes from the CSS `transition` and not jQuery's `animate` I see, never mind that. But I still think the outer Interval should be `duration * 2` as it will take `duration` for the first transition and another `duration` for the one in the setTimeout inside of it.

Comment: Even though, there's a [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/transitionend) event which is dispatched and could serve to trigger the callbacks. I believe a cross-browser solution should be `.on('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend msTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd')` and alternate the `scale(1)`/`scale(2)` properties with a boolean flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class to trigger infinite animations.
This can be imply done by adding a class.

```js
$('#msg').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('loading');
  setTimeout(function(){
      $('#msg').removeClass('loading');
  },2000);
})
```

```css
#msg{font-size:30px;}
#msg.loading{ animation:1s showborder linear infinite}

@keyframes showborder{
from{border: 5px solid red}
to{border: 5px solid green}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msg">Weeeeeee CLICK ME</div>
```

You can read more about [css scroll animation](https://imjignesh.com/how-to-trigger-css-animation-on-scroll/) which basically adds animation using class addition method.